# Missing Nav Mesh in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, navmesh

I wanted to give the monster a NavMeshAgent component, but it is not in the list of components, how can I add it there?

[Click here to view Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFXFC.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Menu: Window > Package Manager
2. On the top left of the window, change **Packages** to **Built-in**
3. Select **AI** from the list
4. Click **Enable** button on the bottom right of the window